# How do I handle multiple web forms sent simultaneously from different devices to one server using python?

Tags: python, forms, http, network-programming

I'm trying to create a website, and one key part of it is a basic form that the user fills in and submits to the server with POST. What will then happen is that the form data will be added to a queue on the server-end, and a python script will take it out the other end, make sense of it, and input it into a database. Simple stuff, but the problem I'm encountering right now is what happens if multiple users each send a form simultaneously. I'm not quite sure how to use python (or javascript if more appropriate) to handle those multiple forms sent and add them to the queue. Any solutions I should consider to address this potential problem?

Comment: It is difficult to say as the information is not sufficient. But I think it is also depends on the Queue you are using. If you are using some third party service for queueing and if it supports multiple writes then I think it should work with concurrent write operations.

Comment: I was planning on using CPython's queue module, which I've seen would be useful for multiple read and write operations.  I'm just not sure on how to have python take in simultaneous POST requests and add the data into the queue.